# Can't fetch local API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, go, https, fetch-api

I coded a crud API by Go. I called it successfully by Postman, but I fetched it by JavaScript and got this error in console:

```
todo.js:14          GET https://10.0.154.123:8080/todos net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
(anonymous) @ todo.js:14
getData @ todo.js:13
(anonymous) @ todo.js:60
todo.js:14          Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at todo.js:14:9
at new Promise (\<anonymous\>)
at getData (todo.js:13:12)
at todo.js:60:1
```

This is my `getData` function in JS:

```js
function getData(urlTail) {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
    // console.log(OK)
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        fetch('http://10.0.154.123:8080/todos', options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
            })
    });
}
```

and code in Go (gin framework):

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/todos", getTodos)
    router.GET("/todo/:id", getTodo)
    router.POST("/todo", addTodo)
    router.DELETE("/todo/:id", removeTodo)
    router.PUT("/todo/:id", updateTodo)
    
    router.Run("10.0.154.123:8080")

}
```

I guess this because it auto changed the protocol to https but I can't fix. Hope to have your help. Thank you.

Comment: you don't need the Promise wrapper - simply `return fetch()...` - fetch returns a promise. Other than that, check your SSL/TLS config on the server.

Comment: also your function has to be asynchronous. async function getData() {...}

Comment: You cannot use the `https` scheme with an IP address; that much is clear.

Comment: Your function does not need to be "async" if you `return fetch()...` as @RandyCasburn suggested, you only need it if you use "await" in the function body

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the secure connection (SSL) when trying to fetch an API through an insecure connection (HTTP) from a webpage served through a secure connection (HTTPS). It is not possible due to [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin%20Policy). To resolve this issue, you should use same protocol (either HTTP or HTTPS) for both server and client.

Comment: No, the issue is not with the SOP. The issue is that the client, for some reason, is using the `https` scheme with an IP address, which doesn't make sense.